# Error in paste using hmd.mx

Tags: r, function, package

I'm a newbie in R and have been suggested to use the package Demography in R. My data will be read in from mortality.org and the package has a function named hmd.mx. Following is run

```
m_data<-hmd.mx("SWE", username@gmail.com, password, "Sweden")
```

The error I get is

```
Error in paste(username, ":", password, sep = "") : 
  object 'username' not found
```

I tried finding similar issue online but find nothing like it. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Do you want that the second parameter has to be "*what_is_in_username_variable@gmail.com*" ?
If it's the case you should put as second parameter `paste0(username,"@gmail.com")`. It will merge the true value that is in `username` variable and the string *@gmail.com*.
If `username@gmail.com` is the name of a variable (But I don't think that it's the case) you should change it and not putting `@` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment. The issue was the missing " around password and username.